# PublishSubject calls map for each present observer

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm using a `PublishSubject` along with `map` operator:

```
@Test
public void testMapWithMultipleObservers() {

    PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    Func1 action = spy(new Func1<Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer integer) {
            return integer;
        }
    });
    Observable<Integer> observable = subject.asObservable().map(action);

    observable.subscribe(mock(Observer.class));
    observable.subscribe(mock(Observer.class));

    subject.onNext(1);

    verify(action, times(2)).call(anyInt());
    // however, I need it to be times(1)

}
```

The desired behaviour is to perform an action after the subject produces a value. I've tried `doOnEach`,`doOnNext`, `map` and in each case the action is performed for each present observer (for 100 observers action would be performed 100 times), while I need it to perform per emission.

Could you suggest anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest option would be to use [share()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#share())

```java
Observable<Integer> observable = 
    subject
        .map(action)
        .share();
```

You don't need the asObservable() call. It is used to return a Subject from an API and prevent the caller from casting it back to a Subject. For example:

```java
Observable<Integer> getSubjectAsObservable() {
    return subject.asObservable();
}
```